# Android TabLayout using android.support.v7.app.ActionBar and android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragments overlay

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I'm quite new to Android programming but I'll do my best to give all the information needed. I'm using the new `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to display a Tab Layout for Android API from 8 to 17.
  I'm facing a problem showing my two fragments correctly in my activity because they overlay each other after I select one of them. So, this is my main activity code:

```java
package it.koopa.scank;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //have to use getSupportActionBar from android.support.v7.app
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        //hello tab
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.tab_hello)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<HelloFragment>(this, "hello", HelloFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        //handle content tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.tab_send)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<HandleContentFragment>(this, "handle", HandleContentFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.scank, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final ActionBarActivity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;

        /**
         * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
         * @param activity The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
         * @param tag The identifier tag for the fragment
         * @param clz The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
         */
        public TabListener(ActionBarActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

            // Check if the fragment is already initialized
            if (mFragment == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(getCorrectActionBarId(), mFragment, mTag);
                Log.i(TAG, "FragID " + mFragment.getId() + ", FragTAG=" + mFragment.getTag() + " ADDED!!!");
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.attach(mFragment);
                Log.i(TAG, "FragID " + mFragment.getId() + ", FragTAG=" + mFragment.getTag() + " attached.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment != null) {
                // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                ft.detach(mFragment);
                Log.i(TAG, "FragID " + mFragment.getId() + ", FragTAG=" + mFragment.getTag() + " detached.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the correct id of the action bar
     * @return
     */
    public static int getCorrectActionBarId () {
        int androidVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (androidVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            return android.R.id.content;
        } else {
            return R.id.action_bar_activity_content;
        }
    }

}
```

And these are my two fragments (both use their own xml layout). First one:

```java
package it.koopa.scank;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HelloFragment extends Fragment {
    private int index;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false);
        Log.i("HelloFragment","I'm " + HelloFragment.class);

        return v;

    }
}
```

and second one:

```
package it.koopa.scank;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HandleContentFragment extends Fragment {
    private int index;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.handle_content, container, false);
        Log.i("HandleContentFragment","I'm " + HandleContentFragment.class);

        return v;

    }
}
```

and, as a result, if I select the second tab, the views are put one over another!
I found a similar question here [Tabs using android.support.v7.app.ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17960127/2519150) but the accepted solution doesn't seem to work for me. In fact, in my main activity you can see I get the content id with

```java
    int androidVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (androidVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return android.R.id.content;
    } else {
        return R.id.action_bar_activity_content;
    }
```

but fragments content is still overlaied (I can't upload images because of my almost-zero reputation).
Where am I wrong?

Update:
My activity uses `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"`. I'm testing on a Nexus i9250 with Android 4.2.1

Comment: Tried substituting `ft.detach(mFragment)` with `ft.remove(mFragment)` but this didn't solved. When I click the second tab it overlay first, when I click back the first it hide the first and keep the second and when I click again the second it hide this one too!
I think the problem is how I handle the `FragmentTransaction`. :(

Comment: I solved in a totally different way, and i like it even more because now I can use swipes too. Following [Swipes Tab Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and adapting it a bit to my needs it now works perfectly! It introduced a little coupling problem betwwen my fragments and my main activity but at least it works smoothly!
So I can confirm that the new libraries can do the job for a tab layout with swipes from Android 2.2 to 4.3! Nice

Comment: You know, put the code of your solution would have been a nice thing...

Comment: @koopa If you **update appcompat-v7 to revision 19.0.0** you do no longer need to switch between `android.R.id.content` and `R.id.action_bar_activity_content`. Read [issue 59077 for more information](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59077).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug.
You can find a workaround here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58602

Comment: +1 Good workaround

Bottom line put this after the last line of your 'onTabUnselected' method:

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        try {
            Method commit = tab.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("commitActiveTransaction");
            commit.setAccessible(true);
            commit.invoke(tab); 
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Have every Fragment implement ActionBar.TabListener. Add these methods below along with the other code in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
     mFragment = new MyFragment();
     ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
     ft.attach(mFragment);      
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(mFragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

You can remove the tab listener from your main activity. This handles all of it.

Comment: Why do I have to do this? Isn't it the same (with a lot more code)?
Could you explain? Thanks

Comment: I believe that the Fragment Transaction is the error for you above. This way is a cleaner way of knowing what tab you are on and what the fragment transaction has added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `ft.show(mfragment)` method in `onTabSelected` and `ft.hide(mfragment)` method in `onTabUnselected`.

Look below

```
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  ft.show(mfragment);
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  ft.hide(mfragment);       
}
```