# Android - ActionBar pre Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

Good evening,

i hope somebody could help me.

Im developing a app where i use the action bar from the support library for pre 3.0-devices, but i have the problem, that espacially on the pre 3.0-devices no action bar is showing. When i use a device, which is higher then 3.0 it works fine.

I've followed these tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding

So my "main activity", which handles the action bar, extends from "ActionBarActivity".

**At these moment i figured out, that my tabs the undoubted cause.**

My code looks like this:

> @Override
>       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           //      setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptmenue_extended);

```
    try {
        Log.d("test", "Set ActionBar...");

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.show();

        Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab();
        tabB.setText("Home");
        tabB.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_home);
        tabB.setTabListener(new TabListener<Startmenue_activity>(this,
                "Start", Startmenue_activity.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tabB);

        Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
        tabA.setText("");
        tabA.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_nachrichten_sel);
        tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<Nachrichten_activity>(this,
                "Nachrichten", Nachrichten_activity.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tabA);

        Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab();
        tabC.setText("");
        tabC.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_favoriten);
        tabC.setTabListener(new TabListener<Favoriten_activity>(this,
                "Favoriten", Favoriten_activity.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tabC);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        HelperClassAlertDialog.zeigeInfoDialog(this, "Error...",
                ex.getMessage(), "");
    }
}
```

When i delete the part of adding the tabs, the action bar works fine! But when i add the "tabs" again, no action bar is showing. But there are also no errors!

I really hope, somebody could help me. :(

**Solution**:

The following question and answer help me:

[Tabs using android.support.v7.app.ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960127/tabs-using-android-support-v7-app-actionbar)

Or this:

[ActionBar with support library and Fragments overlay content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881297/actionbar-with-support-library-and-fragments-overlay-content)

Answer (score -2):

You have to use `ActionBarSherlock`. It's a library. Download it from [this](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) link. [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/action-bar-sherlock-tutorial) is a tutorial on how to use `ActionBarSherlock`.