# App crash when Menu button is pressed on Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

My app has an ActionBar (using Support v7 lib) and there are some actions I'd like to add using the Options menu. I followed this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to implement the bar and the menu, and they appear as expected when the view loads.

The device I'm using to test can fit up to 2 buttons in the action bar, while the remaining should go to the overflow menu.

If I add only two items to the menu, when I press the menu button, nothing will happen, which is fine, since there are no more options to be shown;

If I add a 3rd one, or force one not to be shown on the Action Bar (by setting `showAsAction="never"`), and then I press the Menu button, my app will crash.

Logcat does not register any error messages, but shows these warnings when I press the Menu button:

```
W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/ft5x0x_ts.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65536.devname='ft5x0x_ts'
W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Full log from app initialization until crash moment: http://pastebin.com/gm22H18s

These warnings appear everytime I press the button, regardless which app is running, so I'd say this is unrelated. The downside is that this is the only output on Logcat.

**Update:** my test device runs Android 2.3 and the app is crashing when I run on it. I tested on a KitKat emulator, and it does not crash on it.
I've also tested on a Gingerbread emulator and it also crashes. This way I know my device is not the problem.

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.example.myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        com.example.myapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Search" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_cart"
        com.example.myapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Cart" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_login"
        com.example.myapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Log in" />
</menu>
```

Menu inflation:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Logcat output:

`I/ActivityManager(  277): Start proc com.example.myapp for activity com.example.myapp/.MainActivity: pid=13924 uid=10053 gids={1006, 3003, 1015}`


`W/KeyCharacterMap(13924): Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap(13924): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/ft5x0x_ts.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65536.devname='ft5x0x_ts'
W/KeyCharacterMap(13924): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin`


`I/DEBUG   (13893): Build fingerprint: 'sprd/sprdroid_base/hsdroid:2.3.5/MocorDroid2.3.5/W12.20_P20.01:user/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (13893): pid: 13924, tid: 13924  >>> com.example.myapp <<<
I/DEBUG   (13893): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000001
I/DEBUG   (13893):  r0 00000000  r1 00000007  r2 fffffe84  r3 00000070
I/DEBUG   (13893):  r4 0000bca8  r5 40789b38  r6 ad3889dc  r7 00000001
I/DEBUG   (13893):  r8 003a8d98  r9 003a2e60  10 00000001  fp 41968b08
I/DEBUG   (13893):  ip ad389828  sp befc5358  lr ad356e9d  pc a81155c8  cpsr 20800030
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d8  0000000042900000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d16 003a8d9860000013  d17 003a2e6000000001
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d18 000000060053b820  d19 00000001003a2e60
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d20 ab20faa000000006  d21 ab142fdcbefc5248
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d28 3f137c749114f9db  d29 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (13893):  scr 60000013
I/DEBUG   (13893):
I/DEBUG   (13893):          #00  pc 000155c8  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (13893):          #01  lr ad356e9d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so`

Comment: what's going on with that attribute in your custom namespace?

Comment: According to the tutorial I mentioned, since I'm using the support library, the attribute `showAsAction` is not present in the support library, therefore I need to add my app's namespace/package name.

Comment: You are not collecting logcat properly.  Consider using the commandline tool, so that you find the actual messages generated on app startup and then on its crash.

Comment: @ChrisStratton here's a full log I grabbed from DDMS, from app initialization until crash. Notice my comment at line 152. As I said before, there's no error, just three warnings. Only happens on Gingerbread. http://pastebin.com/gm22H18s

Comment: No, that is **not a full logcat** output.  Rather it has been filtered.  Do not use DDMS, do it from the command line.  **There will be messages generated when an app process crashes** and those are what you need to examine.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok, I saved it, but it's kinda huge. I'm trying to truncate it instants before app launch and after app crash. Any ideas to detect it, or should I just send the 2k-line file?

Comment: Well, obviously anything that refers to erroneous conditions is important.  If you really can't figure it out, put the whole thing on pastebin for now and then you can edit the important part into your question (where it belongs) once identified.

Comment: @ChrisStratton http://pastebin.com/rDqbJgM8 warning are on line 352

Comment: You have a native crash in libutils.so probably cuased by a bad call from libandroid_runtime.so   Most likely this is a subtle bug in the device software rather than a problem in your code.  It is not impossible that the character map warnings are related, but feels unlikely - an obvious test would be to see if those show up in logcat for an app that doesn't crash.

Comment: Yes they do show up everytime I press the button. That's why I suggested the warnings are unrelated. It also happens in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here. It was ok and suddenly stoped. Found the answer at this post

[Menu button crashes application when has overflow actions on API 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578965/menu-button-crashes-application-when-has-overflow-actions-on-api-7)

It was a problem with 0.9.1 graddle PNG cruncher.