# Why the fragment overlaps the Action bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I tried to use the android support library v7 to add an action bar to my activity my extending tht actionbar activity.
A blank fragment has been also built to make a tab.
However, the content of the fragment is overlapping the action bar.
How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I am debugging the app using Android 2.1 Emulator

Comment: Please post your activity layout.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881297/actionbar-with-support-library-and-fragments-overlay-content?rq=1), fixed by using the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read it here [ActionBar with support library and Fragments overlay content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881297/actionbar-with-support-library-and-fragments-overlay-content#17920694) 
I am sure it will help you :

For pre ICS devices you must use:

```
R.id.action_bar_activity_content
```

instead of

```
android.R.id.content
```

R.id.action_bar_activity_content is a new id used in layout for displaying app content, it would appear that it replace android.R.id.content when you use support v7 appcompat ActionBarActivity.

You can use this code to retrieve the correct id of the activity content :

```
public static int getContentViewCompat() {
return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ?
           android.R.id.content : R.id.action_bar_activity_content;
}
```

Comment: The issue has been fixed. Please read [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59077).