# fragment contents overlaps tabs. Check my screen shot

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

[image]

I cannot perform any click action on tabs after the contents added. But its working before adding those items.

I am using tab with action bar for the first time, using android support library.
the android icon, the texts, 'book now' button are belongs to the home tab. i want it all under home tab.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you atleast post some of the code coz tabs can be defined in so many ways are some ways are deprecated by the android platform they are no longer recommended.
However this is probably the best tutorial I have seen,every tab has it's own layout and class so makes things pretty easy:
 http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: cannot run it api level less than 11.

Comment: I am extending main activity with ActionBarActivity and using a custom tablistner.

Comment: So code?? have u taken a good look at this example though? are u targetting APIs lower than 11 as well?

Comment: yes.. i got the soln. from this link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043606/why-the-fragment-overlaps-the-action-bar

thanks buddy.