# getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, f) not working

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-actionbar-compat

```
// Place an ArticleFragment as our content pane
final ArticleFragment f = new ArticleFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, f).commit();
```

This lines of code are from the [NewsReader sample app](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Why they are not working if the activity extends [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)? Everything works fine if the activity extends FragmentActivity.

**Update:**

Not working means: The ArticleFragment don't becomes visible and it happens on devices with Android < 4.x, maybe < 3.x but I don't have a device with Android 3.x to test it.

Why?

Ralph

Comment: Please edit your question to explain **completely and precisely** what "not working" means, rather than expecting us to guess.

Comment: Not working means: The ArticleFragment don't becomes visible.

Comment: the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881297/actionbar-with-support-library-and-fragments-overlay-content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`android.R.id.content` does not work on Android 2.3 and below when using `ActionBarActivity`. [There is a bug filed for this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58108&can=1&q=android.R.id.content&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), though I am skeptical that it will get addressed. The only workaround I found was to call `setContentView()` with your own `FrameLayout` and use it as the target of your `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: by workaround you mean defining fragment in layout file and then creating it during setContentView()? This way I am not able to pass arguments to my fragment.

Comment: ok, I solved it by calling getActivity().getIntent().getExtras(). I hope google will release fixed support lib sonner than later.

Comment: @marcin_j: "by workaround you mean defining fragment in layout file and then creating it during setContentView()?" -- I have no idea if that works, and that is not what I wrote. When I wrote `FragmentTransaction`, I meant `FragmentTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it should extend SherlockFragmentActivity or any other support library, as  for previous android versions you will have to add a support library to your lib folder,

However the getSupportFragmentManager works for previous android versions in other words before version 11 if you want your application to work as it is change the getSupportFragmentManager into getFragmentManager and change your minSdkVersion into 11 and targeted into 17, good luck

Comment: ActionBarActivity is the new "ActionBarSherlock" from Google. It has nothing to do with ABS and ActionBarActivity itself extends FragmentActivity. ActionBarActivity is from SupportLibrary.